# css style overwrite when using turbolinks in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I use turbolinks in my rails4 project.

I notice it will add all *.css file as external css link in html head.
Css style may be overwrite if someone uses the same css selector as I do!

And here is my question:
Is there any setting in turbolinks to ignore certain css/js loading on specified page?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a job for conditional `ERB` code, not turbolinks (but I could be wrong)

[Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) is a javascript library to load the `<body`> tag of a page via ajax (keeping `<head>` intact. You can make Turbolinks load independently by applying the [**`data-no-turbolink`**](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks) tag to your links:

```
<div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
```

I would do this:

```
<head>
   <% if x.present? %>
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "your_css" %>
   <% end %>
</head>
```

---

In terms of specific assets / styles, you may wish to look at [**asset change detection**](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#asset-change-detection):

> You can track certain assets, like application.js and application.css,
>   that you want to ensure are always of the latest version inside a
>   Turbolinks session. This is done by marking those asset links with
>   data-turbolinks-track

---

Lastly, your question is very ambiguous (not enough context). When you mention:

> I notice it will add all *.css file as external css link in html head. Css style may be overwrite if someone uses the same css selector as I do!

If your CSS is [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), your issue is likely with how you've structured your assets, rather than Turbolinks. You should give more details on how you're loading your CSS & what it needs to bring back